# How to declare string array in c

Tags: c, arrays, string

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
int i;
string A[]={"Ahmet", "Mehmet", "Bulent", "Fuat"};

for(i=0;i<=3;i++){
printf("%s",A[i]);
}
return 0;
}
```

How can i see my array's elements as output?

Compiler says "'string' undeclared".

Comment: There's no type `string` in C.

Comment: Beware that input characters as your `ü` in `"Bülent"` may not show up as just one `char` as you C compiler understands it.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This way:

```
 char *A[] = {"Ahmet", "Mehmet", "Bülent", "Fuat"};
```

`A` is an array of pointers to `char`.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Basic structure, but it can not been remembered easily.

Answer (score 6):

```
const char *A[] = {"Ahmet", "Mehmet", "Bülent", "Fuat"};
```

If you don't include the `const`, it will work but the compiler will give you annoying warnings unless you suppress them with "-w".

Answer (score 1):

In C, a string can only be represented, as an array of characters.So, to represent an array of strings you have to make array of (array of characters). In C++ we have a STL called, string and you can make an array of string and use it in the the way you have written(ofcourse with modifications to C specific stuff in your code).

Answer (score 0):

you can use  [cs50](https://github.com/cs50/libcs50) library to work with string or you can work with pointers.

**CS50**

```
string names[] = {"Mohammed", "Mhammed", "Ali", "Lora"};
```

**pointer**

```
char *names[] = {"Mohammed", "Mhammed", "Ali", "Lora"};
```